# How to use SharedPreferences to save my checkbox state in Android Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, checkbox, xamarin.android, sharedpreferences

I have two activitys, the MainActivity and Pagina_1Activity.

In MainActivity i have a button that goes to the Pagina_1Activity using Intent.
In Pagina_1Activity i have a checkbox and a imageView. When i check the checkbox it changes the image in imageView and that is working great.

What i am trying to do is to save the checkbox state using the SharedPreferences, and i am trying to do that using an integer value, the "int estado".

What i want to do is:  if i go back to MainActivity or close de app, it saves the checkbox (if it is checkd stay checked).

Can anyone help me with this and tell me why my sharedpreferences dont work? I am trying for days .. with no solution...

```
CheckBox checkbox;
    ImageView imageView;
    int estado;
    private ISharedPreferencesEditor editarEstado;
    private ISharedPreferences valorEstado;


    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Pagina_1);

        //here i am trying to get the value of the estado for my checkbox state
        valorEstado = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("valorE", FileCreationMode.Private);
        var pegar = valorEstado.GetInt("Estado", 0);


        checkbox = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkBox1);
        imageView = FindViewById <ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);

        checkbox.Click += delegate
        {
            if (checkbox.Checked)
            {
                estado = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                estado = 0;
            }

            if (estado == 1)
            {
                checkbox.Checked = true;
                imageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.guildwars_icone);
            }
            if (estado == 0)
            {
                checkbox.Checked = false;
                imageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.guardian);
            }

            //here i am trying to save the value of estado for my checkbox state
            valorEstado = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("valorE", FileCreationMode.Private);
            editarEstado = valorEstado.Edit();
            editarEstado.PutInt("Estado", estado);

            editarEstado.Commit();

        };         


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this way

To save bool value

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (this);
ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit ();
editor.PutBoolean ("bool_value", mBool);
editor.Commit();
```

To Retrive the bool value

```
ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences (this);
mBool = prefs.GetBoolean ("bool_value", <default value>);
```

Comment: Ok, im using your code, but i use PutInt and GetInt for my "estado" value because it is an integer is this correct?
The problem is i get an error in (mContext): 

CS0103 - The name 'mContext' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Also i get this error in "prefs"

CS0136  C# A local or parameter named cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

Comment: Sorry i am new with this.. where and how i get my activity context?

Comment: @FelipeMachado if you are in Activity just use `this` place of `mContext`.. See my update answer.

Comment: Thanks for helping me! One more question.. how can i solve the other  error in "prefs"? - CS0136

Comment: @FelipeMachado can you specified more I can't understand what you say `CS0136` ??

Comment: I get this error in "prefs" (in the part where i try to retrive) 

CS0136 C# A local or parameter named cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter

Comment: @FelipeMachado Remove this line `ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);` because you are using it 2 times.

Comment: Ok, it is still not working.. maybe it is my conditional structure?

Answer (score 0):

@Ironman here is the code.

```
 CheckBox checkbox;
    ImageView imageView;
    int estado = 0;
    private ISharedPreferencesEditor editor;
    private ISharedPreferences prefs;


    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Pagina_1);

        //here i am trying to get the value of estado for my checkbox state
        ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        estado = prefs.GetInt("int_value", 0);

        checkbox = FindViewById<CheckBox>(Resource.Id.checkBox1);
        imageView = FindViewById <ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);

        checkbox.Click += delegate
        {
            if (checkbox.Checked)
            {
                estado = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                estado = 0;
            }

            if (estado == 1)
            {
                checkbox.Checked = true;
                imageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.guildwars_icone);
            }
            if (estado == 0)
            {
                checkbox.Checked = false;
                imageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.guardian);
            }

            //THE ERRO CS0136 IS IN THIS prefs
            ISharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.GetDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = prefs.Edit();
            editor.PutInt("int_value", estado);
            editor.Commit();

        };




    }
```